# Website Graphics Smooth Transitions

Tags: javascript, web

So I'm fairly new to PHP, but I have a project I'm working on and I've got a doubt about a specific aspect of web development.

My website has a major requirement, it needs to be very user friendly, and it has a lot of information that will be displayed in graphs (pie charts, column/line graphs).

My question is regarding aesthetics: is it possible to implement a smooth transition like the one microsoft office 2013 uses regarding its graphs?

If you have used ms office 2013, one thing that I noticed was its flow, and I would like to implement that feature in my website when changing values in one graph. Of course I'd much rather have functionality over looks, but if I can have both, it would be great.

This is my fisrt question here and I have searched this subject, but I haven't got any useful tip. Anyhow, if you give me some pointers on this subject (basically if it really is doable or not), I'd really appreciate it.

Cheers.

Comment: So what does this have to do with PHP? Sounds like more of Javascript/HTML5 functionality.

Comment: I'm using PHP to develop the site, it will contain html as well, but it will mostly have PHP scripts.

Comment: You will need to have Javascript / JQuery in order for a smooth "flow" Php is only server based information, so it doesn't do anything 'flow' like. It is also completely do-able. Several sites do that.

Comment: PHP is a server-side language and does not handle user interaction.

Comment: I just wanted to now if there were anything that could perform this type of action, I'll look it JQuery for it. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language. In order to change anything DOM related after the page loads, you need to use JavaScript.

[jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) looks okay for what you need. You could also look at [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/), and [D3](http://d3js.org/) is great for graphs. [Visibile.io](http://visible.io/) is a charting DSL for D3 that would make it way easier to make charts.